# How to put relation based filed into the CONCAT with DB::raw in Laravel 6?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

In my Laravel 6.x app I need to return a specific format to the frontend and I need to use my model's relations to give correct result.

I have this code:

```php
BankAccount::with(['deviza'])
    ->whereOr([['bank_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$term.'%']])
    ->whereOr([['bankaccount_number', 'LIKE', '%'.$term.'%']])
    ->get([
        "id",
        DB::raw("bankaccount_number AS name"),
        DB::raw("CONCAT(".
            "'bank_name:', bank_name, ".
            "'|deviza:', deviza.code, ".
            "'|swift_code:', swift_code, ".
            "'|iban_code:', iban_code, ".
            "'|description:', description) AS description"),
        DB::raw("'bank_account' AS type"),
        DB::raw("'BankAccount' AS found_model_name"),
    ]);
```

The point is the `deviza.code` in a `DB::raw()`. With this code I get this error message:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'deviza.code' in 'field list'
(SQL: select `id`, bankaccount_number AS name, CONCAT('bank_name:', bank_name, '|deviza:',
deviza.code, '|swift_code:', swift_code, '|iban_code:', iban_code, '|description:', description)
AS description, 'bank_account' AS type, 'BankAccount' AS found_model_name from `bank_accounts`
where `bank_accounts`.`deleted_at` is null)
```

How can I put my relation based `deviza.code` filed into the `CONCAT()`? Is there any best practice to do this?

Comment: You're going to need a join. `with` creates a second query based on the BankAccount query.

Comment: Isn't there any built-in solution for this? In this case not so painful, but in case of morphToMany... that will be not really nice & Laravel-conform

Comment: you are already getting the information using ::with, and get() returns a collection. You could manipulate your results in the collection rather than in the query.

Comment: is there some kind of relation between bankaccount and deviza tables?

Comment: yes, on `BankAccount` is this relation `$this->belongsTo(Deviza::class, 'deviza_id');`